System freezes when using write() on gadgetfs device
I am working on creating a USB device using a single-board computer (specifically a Rock Pi S), and to enable USB device functionality I am using GadgetFS with raw vendor bulk and interrupt endpoints.
My program works the first time I try it. I can connect to the USB device and read/write to it from a host computer.
However, if I put the device into a suspend state, for example by putting the host computer in sleep mode, and then try to restart the program on the device, the whole system freezes when I first try to write() to the gadgetfs file descriptor. Not just my program, but the entire machine. My ssh connections become unresponsive, I cannot ping the machine anymore, etc.
I have tried to reset everything by closing the program, unmounting gadgetfs, and writing a reset bit to the USB controller on the processor, in between these suspend events, but when I set everything up again and restart the program, the system still freezes. So I don't think it has anything to do with my own code, rather that there is something deep down in the system that reaches an unrecoverable state which manifests the next time I try to write to the driver.
My question is how can I troubleshoot this kind of problem in general? Since the entire machine just freezes, I don't get any error codes of what the problem is, I cannot do anything except cut power to force a reboot.

For the record, I was able to avoid this by not trying to open the device file more than one time. Previously I would close and then open it again and the second time I did that is when the freeze happens.

One possible fix may be updating your host system to use Kernel V6.8. I am unfamiliar with gadgetfs but have experienced issues similar to what you are describing, ie. system hanging perpetually, while writing to a HID device with the USBHID module. In my experience, upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel V5.15) to 22.04 (Kernel V6.8) resolved the issue.
